# ExpandableListView#setOnClickListener & ExpandableListView#setOnGroupClickListener are not working anymore in API 26+?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I have a code which is running for several years through most of android versions.

Today I realise that it's not working anymore in API 26+

This is my code:

```
    mChapters = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.chapter_list);
    mChapters.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
    mChapterAdapter = new ChapterListViewAdapter(this);
    mChapters.setAdapter(mChapterAdapter);

    mChapters.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            SectionTitle section = (SectionTitle) mChapterAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getInstance(), getSectionTextActivityClass());
            intent.putExtra(AbstractSectionTextActivity.SECTION_ID, section.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    });

    mChapters.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            SectionTitle section = (SectionTitle) mChapterAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (section.getChildCount() == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AbstractMainActivity.this, getSectionTextActivityClass());
                intent.putExtra(AbstractSectionTextActivity.GROUP_ID, section.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I tested it in AVD - Nexus API 24,25,26,27.
For Nexus API <= 25, it's working normally - I'm able to click onto the group item and child item.
From Nexus API 26+, nothing happens when I try to click onto the group item and child item.

Any ideas why or was the API changed?

Comment: do you want to use an external library to solve the problem?

Comment: @TuấnKiệt if it's fast. but I want to understand the problem first. Know what is the problem, then easier to fix it.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but why you even border, Expandable ListView is an old API by the way, just you a library instead, make your life simple